# How to log slow HTTP responses

Tags: httpd, lighttpd, apache-2.4

How does one log slow HTTP responses? I'm using Lighttpd, but could switch to another webserver if necessary.

Apache can log response times, but not conditionally, it seems.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html

Apache Bench and httping are useful client-side for some general testing but aren't useful for long term logging.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the piped logs functionality to achieve this? You'll probably have to write your own shell script to write the "slow responses" to a separate file, but you're in complete control here.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#piped